# Multiple drawers in react-navigation 5.0

Tags: react-navigation

I wrote below code to make multiple side menus but it occurred error

> Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or "Screen". Make sure each navigator is under a separate "Screen" container.

However I've tried to find the Container for multiple drawers but no luck.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationNativeContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Container, Text, Button } from 'native-base';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'

function BlankScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Text>Blank</Text>
);
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Container style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Menu')}>
        <Text>Go to Menu</Text>
      </Button>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Favorit')}>
        <Text>Go to Favorit</Text>
      </Button>
    </Container>
);
}

function MenuScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Container style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>Go back home</Text>
      </Button>
    </Container>
);
}

function FavoritScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Container style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column-inverse' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>Go back home</Text>
      </Button>
  </Container>
);
}

const DrawerL = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerR = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <NavigationNativeContainer>
        <DrawerL.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerPosition="left">
          <DrawerL.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <DrawerL.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />
          <DrawerL.Screen name="Favorit" component={FavoritScreen} />
        </DrawerL.Navigator>
        <DrawerR.Navigator initialRouteName="Blank" drawerPosition="right">
          <DrawerR.Screen name="Blank" component={BlankScreen} />
          <DrawerR.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />
          <DrawerR.Screen name="Favorit" component={FavoritScreen} />
        </DrawerR.Navigator>
      </NavigationNativeContainer>
    </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you wrote it won't work, because consider this: you've 2 drawers, one has initial route as "Home", and other as "Blank". Which one should be rendered?

Here, you need to follow the same approach as React Navigation 4, put one drawer inside another:

```js
function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Favorit" component={FavoritScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function RightDrawer() {
  return (
    <DrawerR.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerPosition="right">
      <DrawerR.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <DrawerR.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />
      <DrawerR.Screen name="Favorit" component={FavoritScreen} />
    </DrawerR.Navigator>
  )
}

function LeftDrawer() {
  return (
    <DrawerL.Navigator initialRouteName="RightDrawer" drawerPosition="left">
      <DrawerL.Screen name="RightDrawer" component={RightDrawer} />
    </DrawerL.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationNativeContainer>
      <LeftDrawer />
    </NavigationNativeContainer>
  )
}
```

Since your left drawer won't show the screens that you have in Stack, you will need to provide a custom component for your drawer which lists the screens: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-drawercontent

Comment: When i click on left button adn calling onPress with this.props.navigation.openDrawer(). But it is opening left drawer only. How to open right drawer. I need both left and right drawer at a time. which means if i click left menu button, it should open left drawer and right menu sholud open right drawer. Can you help me this ?

Comment: @MaheshPeri use `navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().openDrawer()` to open the parent drawer

Comment: Thank you satya164. It is working fine. I used double time dangerous parent method like              
 
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().openDrawer to open right drawer. Because i am nesting Leftdrawer in other rootstack navigator.

Comment: navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().dangerouslyGetParent().openDrawer() really rocks

Comment: Parents are no longer dangrous! :-), now we can write the less ridiculous navigation.getParent().getParent().openDrawer() (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x#dropped-dangerously-from-dangerouslygetparent-and-dangerouslygetstate) - but be sure to check for undefined... cheers