# Using 2 Drawer Navigator in one project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 2 DrawerNavigators, one of them(PaymentHistoryDrawer) is inside the BottomTabNavigator. I bind them to two buttons - the 1st for the HamburgerMenu , the 2nd for the FilterButton inside Payment History.

```
export const DrawerNavigator = () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <Sidebar {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name={SCREEN_ROOT} component={BottomTabNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
);

export const DrawerPaymentHistoryNavigator = () => (
    <PaymentHistoryDrawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={PaymentHistorySidebar}
        drawerPosition="right"
        drawerStyle={{
            zIndex: 0,
            width: 300
        }}
        drawerType="front">
        <PaymentHistoryDrawer.Screen
            name={SCREEN_PAYMENT_HISTORY_DRAWER}
            component={HistoryScreen}
            options={{ title: 'My home' }}
        />
    </PaymentHistoryDrawer.Navigator>
);
```

I initialize them differently and bind them differently as "Drawer" for Hamburger Menu, "PaymentHistoryDrawer" for Filters. But anyway, when I click, let's say, on the Hamburger Menu button in the Bottom tab, where at the same time there is FilterButton, that calls PaymentHistoryDrawer, the PaymentHistory comes out. Why are they related to each other? how to untie?

```
//this code is the beginning of the above written code
type DrawerParamList = {
    [SCREEN_ROOT]: undefined;
};

type PaymentHistoryDrawerParamList = {
    [SCREEN_PAYMENT_HISTORY_DRAWER]: undefined;
};
export type RootScreenNavigationProp = DrawerNavigationProp<
    DrawerParamList,
    'SCREEN_ROOT'
>;

export type PaymentHistoryScreenNavigationProp = DrawerNavigationProp<
    PaymentHistoryDrawerParamList,
    'SCREEN_PAYMENT_HISTORY_DRAWER'
>;

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerParamList>();
const PaymentHistoryDrawer =
    createDrawerNavigator<PaymentHistoryDrawerParamList>();
```

Binding ToggleDrawer to the FilterButton

```
export const FilterButton = () => {
    const { toggleDrawer } =
        useNavigation<PaymentHistoryScreenNavigationProp>();

    return (
        <FilterContainer onPress={toggleDrawer}>
            <Image source={FilterIcon} />
            <FilterText>Фильтры</FilterText>
        </FilterContainer>
    );
};
```

Binding ToggleDrawer to the HamburgerMenuButton

```
const _Menu = () => {
    const { toggleDrawer } = useNavigation<RootScreenNavigationProp>();

    return <Icon onPress={toggleDrawer} />;
};

export const Menu = memo(_Menu);
```

Additional question : ToggleDrawer is UseNavigation tool. Can it take any additional arguments? I read 2 times documentation, but didn't find anything about arguments or props. Thanks!

Comment: Follow this instructions to constructing your screen and use `navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().toggleDrawer()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638040/multiple-drawers-in-react-navigation-5-0

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still secret...
I hope u're don't using drawers like this