# how to handle two drawers separately in react navigation 6?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6, react-native-drawer

**I have created two Drawer Navigators**

```
const MenuDrawerRight = createDrawerNavigator();
const MenuDrawerLeft = createDrawerNavigator();

function RightDrawerScreens() {
  return (
    <MenuDrawerRight.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <RightDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerType: 'back',
        drawerPosition: 'right',
      }}>
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
    </MenuDrawerRight.Navigator>
  );
}

function LeftDrawerScreens() {
  return (
    <MenuDrawerLeft.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <LeftDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <MenuDrawerLeft.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
      <MenuDrawerLeft.Screen name="DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
    </MenuDrawerLeft.Navigator>
  );
}
```

created separate components for getting drawer content.

Now how to wrap these two drawers in one navigator and how to open these drawers separately(Open one drawer on first button click and open second drawer on second button click)

please ask in comment section if you need any other details.

Comment: put one drawer inside another and try  like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638040/multiple-drawers-in-react-navigation-5-0).

Answer (score 4):

I wrapped one drawer in another drawer like this

```
function MenuDrawerScreen() {
  return (
    <MenuDrawerRight.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <RightDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerType: 'back',
        drawerPosition: 'right',
      }}
      initialRouteName="MenuScreen">
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="MenuScreen" component={Menu} />
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="DashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="LeftDrawer" component={LeftDrawerScreens} />
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <MenuDrawerRight.Screen name="Logout" component={Logout} />
    </MenuDrawerRight.Navigator>
  );
}

function LeftDrawerScreens() {
  return (
    <MenuDrawerLeft.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <LeftDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <MenuDrawerLeft.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuDrawerScreen} />
    </MenuDrawerLeft.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and then used `navigation.getParent().openDrawer()` to open parent drawer and `navigation.openDrawer()` to open child drawer